# Is it possible to install a system app on thousands of tablets by the same google account?

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I need to install a system app on 5000 tablets
Should I use amazon link or just publishing to play store while using the same google account?

Could I use the same google account on all of these devices?

Comment: If I understand correctly , you need to upload your app to a select number of users. If so you can privately deploy your app to the store and add specific organizations that can download your app. Check this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139?hl=en)

Comment: @AhmadSabeh Android Enterprise only supported by google tablets, not any tablets
My question could I use the same account for thousands of devices?

Comment: `Android Enterprise only supported by google tablets,` this is wrong. It is supported on all Android devices with Android 6+ (as I remember)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko check the requirements page https://www.android.com/enterprise/recommended/requirements/?_ga=2.185204590.63573807.1564556102-1684132408.1562040968